# How do I add a new configuration to my environment using comfy?

Tags: configuration

Using [comfy](https://github.com/marmelab/comfygure), how can I add a new configuration to my environment ?

- Environment: production
- Configuration file: config.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can type `comfy help` to make this appear:

[image]

The right command is: `comfy setall production config.json`